# Could not find library corresponding to plugin

Tags: ros, gazebo, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I make a simulation to check if my program is correct. After I transferred my code on Turtlebot PC to one on Another PC, I executed catkin_make. After that, I checked that there is libompl_planner_rrt.so in /catkin_ws/devel/lib.
I got the next error message, but I'm not sure.

```
[FATAL] [1404362140.989502266, 6.774000000]: Failed to create the ompl_planner_rrt/OMPLPlannerRRT planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: Could not find library corresponding to plugin ompl_planner_rrt/OMPLPlannerRRT. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
```

Could anybody tell me a clue?

I have already added plugin.xml to package.xml.

```
 <export>
    <nav_core plugin="/home/kmurata/catkin_ws/src/ompl_planner_rrt/bgp_plugin.xml"/>
 </export>
```

I executed `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core`.

```
navfn /home/kmurata/catkin_ws/src/navfn/bgp_plugin.xml
goal_passer /home/kmurata/catkin_ws/src/goal_passer/bgp_plugin.xml
ompl_planner_rrt /home/kmurata/catkin_ws/src/ompl_planner_rrt/bgp_plugin.xml
base_local_planner /home/kmurata/catkin_ws/src/base_local_planner/blp_plugin.xml
carrot_planner /home/kmurata/catkin_ws/src/carrot_planner/bgp_plugin.xml
global_planner /home/kmurata/catkin_ws/src/global_planner/bgp_plugin.xml
clear_costmap_recovery /home/kmurata/catkin_ws/src/clear_costmap_recovery/ccr_plugin.xml
rotate_recovery /home/kmurata/catkin_ws/src/rotate_recovery/rotate_plugin.xml
dwa_local_planner /home/kmurata/catkin_ws/src/dwa_local_planner/blp_plugin.xml
move_slow_and_clear /home/kmurata/catkin_ws/src/move_slow_and_clear/recovery_plugin.xml
eband_local_planner /home/kmurata/catkin_ws/src/eband_local_planner/elp_plugin.xml
```

This means that ompl_planner_rrt is registered. Am I wrong?
Now I'm trying simulation with Gazebo, rviz and Turtlebot3D model.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182618/could-not-find-library-corresponding-to-plugin/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That probably means that you forgot to register your plugin in *package.xml* and create the *plugin description file* as explained in http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-07-03**:
Thank you, Martin Peris! I have already add a plugin.xml to package.xml. Is this wrong? What should I do when I transfer my code on a PC to one on an other PC? I'm sorry, I have executed my code on my Turtlebot PC.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-07-04**:
To transfer your code from one PC to another, should be enough to copy your package folder from the catkin environment in the origin PC to the catkin environment on the destination PC. Then just run catkin_make on the destination PC. It should work

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-07-04**:
I think so, but I got same error message. I'm not sure how I should do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rviz it can be checked with the following option:

`rviz --log-level-debug`

It will show a list of paths it tried to find the library.
In my case, `<library path=" ... ">` was wrong in `plugin_description.xml`

---

Originally posted by [*andrei*](https://answers.ros.org/users/57604/_andrei_/) with karma: 11 on 2020-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1